# wget randomly changes source url

Tags: wget

I wanted to write a little script using **wget** to get some files. I was using the direct URL and everything seemed to work nice. After the script finished its work I checked the directories for the files and some were missing. I took a closer look at the terminal and I found that wget somehow managed to change the source URL. It either just typed some random characters or it changed 4 characters from the original URL to **wget**.

Here's a screen so you know what I mean:

[image: terminal and source code]

Is this a known problem?

I tried wget with several added options none of them worked for me:

- **wget**
- **wget -c**
- **wget -r -np -nc --restrict-file-names=nocontrol**

If you need to have a closer look at the whole source code, here it is:

```
mkdir ETH
cd ETH
mkdir Analysis\ I Lineare\ Algebra Diskrete\ Mathematik Einfuehrung\ in\ die\ Programmierung
cd Analysis\ I
mkdir Serien Loesungen Skript
cd ..
cd Lineare\ Algebra
mkdir Serien Loesungen Skript
cd ..
cd Diskrete\ Mathematik
mkdir Serien Loesungen
cd ..
cd Einfuehrung\ in\ die\ Programmierung
mkdir Serien Loesungen Probeklausuren Vorlesungsfolien Uebungsfolien
cd ..


cd Analysis\ I
cd Serien
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie01-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie02-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie03-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie04-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie05-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie06-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie07-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie08-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie09-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie10-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie11-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie12-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie13-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Serie14-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
cd ..
cd Loesungen
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung01-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung02-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung03-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung04-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung05-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung06-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung07-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung08-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung09-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung10-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung11-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung12-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung13-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
wget -c https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2015/other/analysis1_infk/Loesung14-Ana1-D-INFK.pdf
cd ..
cd Skript
wget -c http://www.math.ethz.ch/~struwe/Skripten/InfAnalysis-bbm-8-11-2010.pdf
cd ../..

cd Lineare\ Algebra
cd Serien
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s01.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s02.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s02.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s03.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s04.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s05.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s05.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s06.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s07.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s08.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s09.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s10.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s11.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s12.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/exercisesheets/s13.pdf
cd ..
cd Loesungen
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l01.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l02.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l03.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l04.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l05.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l06.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l07.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l08.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l09.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l10.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l11.pdf
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l12.pdf

wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l01.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l02.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l03.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l04.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l05.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l06.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l07.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l08.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l09.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l10.zip
wget -c http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/linalg/mastersolutions/l11.zip
cd ..
cd Skript
wget -c http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~mhg/unt/LA/HS07/LAS07.pdf
cd ../..

cd Diskrete\ Mathematik
cd Serien
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u01.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u02.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u03.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u04.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u05.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u06.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u07.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u08.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u09.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u10.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u11.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u12.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u13.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/u14.pdf
cd ..
cd Loesungen
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l01.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l02.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l03.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l04.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l05.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l06.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l07.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l08.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l09.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l10.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l11.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l12.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l13.pdf
wget -c http://www.crypto.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/DM15/l14.pdf
cd ../..

cd Einfuehrung\ in\ die\ Programmierung
cd Serien
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/01/assignment_1.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/02/assignment_2.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/03/assignment_3.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/04/assignment_4.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/05/assignment_5.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/06/assignment_6.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/07/assignment_7.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/08/assignment_8.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/09/assignment_9.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/10/assignment_10.pdf
cd ..
cd Loesungen
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/02/assignment_2_solution.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/03/assignment_3_solution.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/04/assignment_4_solution.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/05/assignment_5_solution.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/06/assignment_6_solution.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/07/assignment_7_solution.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/08/assignment_8_solution.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/09/assignment_9_solution.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/assignments/10/assignment_10_solution.pdf
cd ..
cd Probeklausuren
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/mock_exams/1/exam.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/mock_exams/1/solution.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/mock_exams/2/exam.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/mock_exams/2/solution.pdf
cd ..
cd Vorlesungsfolien
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/01_overview.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/02_objects.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/03_conventions.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/04_interface.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/05_logic.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/06_creation.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/07_references_assignments.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/08_bnf.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/08_control.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/09_abstraction.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/10_dynamic_model.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/11_inheritance.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/12_recursion.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/13_data_structures.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/15_topological_sort.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/14_multiple_inheritance.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/18_undo.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/17_agents.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/lectures/19_software_engineering.pdf
cd ..
cd Uebungsfolien
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/exercise_sessions/exercise_session_02cm.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/exercise_sessions/exercise_session_03cm.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/exercise_sessions/exercise_session_04cm.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/exercise_sessions/exercise_session_05cm.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/exercise_sessions/exercise_session_06cm.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/exercise_sessions/exercise_session_07cm.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/exercise_sessions/exercise_session_09cm.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/exercise_sessions/exercise_session_10cm.pdf
wget -c http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2015b_fall/eprog/exercise_sessions/exercise_session_13cm.pdf
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Example mangled output? Please add it to the question.

Comment: I don't understand the output in the terminal window. Did you copy and paste the script commands directly into a terminal?

Comment: @rici yes indeed, I did copy the script commands directly into the terminal

Comment: @Lars: You should just use the `source` command to run the script. Large copy-and-paste operations into terminal windows tend to get corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corruption is happening in your terminal window, long before `wget` sees any command.

Corruption is very common when you do large copy-and-paste operations into terminal sessions running bash. Copy and paste doesn't play well with the way `bash` reads from the terminal.

You should run your script file directly, using the `source` command (also called `.`), or by starting a subshell.

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't know that. This was the first time I tried such a large command. It worked perfectly with the `source` command.